# Delete set of directories

Tags: php, directory

I would like to delete set of directories but 1st I'm gonna have to get the directories names so suppose I've the following site `www.my_site.com` and would use the following code to get all directories names.

```
$get_dirs = glob("*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

for ($i=0;$i<count($get_dirs);$i++){
echo $get_dirs[$i].'+'; // Will show results divided by + sign
}
```

suppose the results as following (if I've 5 directories and note it divided by + sign)

```
dir1+dir2+dir3+dir4+dir5+
```

to use it

```
rrmdir(dir1); // that would delete only directory dir1
```

**My Question**

How to explode the results of directories names `dir1+dir2+dir3+dir4+dir5+` based on the + sign and loop using delete function on all so finally all directories `dir1 and dir2 and dir3 and dir4 and dir5` are deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered Your own question there actually:

```
$dirs = explode('+', $get_dirs);
foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
    rrmdir($dir);
}
```

or did i understand something wrong? And why don't you do it already in for cycle?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what your trying to do?

```
 $dir  = trim('dir1+dir2+dir3+dir4+dir5+', '+');
 $arr = explode("+", $dir);

 foreach ($arr as $a){
      rrmdir($a);
 }
```

You have a extra '+' at the end, so trim($val ,'+')